# how set squid to allow traffic if dansguardian goes down

Tags: squid, endian-firewall, dansguardian

I'm running Endian Firewall Community 2.4.1 (http://www.endian.com/it/community/efw-24/)
At the moment, an annoying bug affect my installation (http://bugs.endian.com/view.php?id=3221)
and I would configure squid to allow traffic if dansguardian goes down.
Is there a way to do that? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's not a way to do this in Endian from withing the web interface.  Have you looked into updating clam-av?  I've had that solve similar problems in Endian.

Comment: can you post me informations how to update clamav?

Comment: What does "rpm -q efw-clamav" show?  You can try "yum update efw-clamav".  I'd also run "freshclam" to see what the output is.

Answer (score 0):

Current Endian (3.2) version doesn't use dansguardian anymore but c-icap and is monitored by monit to make sure the process used for antivirus and content filter is always up and running.
So the linked bug is definitely disappeared, the new bug tracker is https://jira.endian.com

Answer (score -1):

You can monitor from time to time if dansguardian fails and then restart it - write a script.

Comment: Really, you think?  Not that I'm the one who downvoted this, but it's not a useful answer.  Saying "script something" is like saying "fix it."  Yeah, duh.  The question would be about how to fix it, not whether to fix it or not.